# Regex For All String Except Certain Characters

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that matches a certain word that is not preceded by 2 dashes (--) or a slash and a star (/*). I tried some expression but none seem to work.

Below is the text I am testing on

> a_func(some_param);
>
> /* a comment initialization */
>
> init;

I am trying to write a regex that will only match the word `init` in the last line alone, what I've tried so far is matching the word `init` in `initialization` and the last line, I tried to look for existing answers, and found that used negative lookahead, but it was still matching `init` in `initialization`. Below are the expressions I tried:

- `(?!\/\*).*(init)`
- `[^(\-\-|\/\*)].*(init)`
- `(?<!\/\*).*(init)` While reading in regex101's quick reference, I found this negative lookbehind which I believe had a similar example to what I need but I was still not able to get what I want, should I look into the negative lookbehind more or is this not how I achieve what I want?

My knowledge in regular expression is not that extensive, so I don't know if it is possible for what I want or not, but is it doable?

Comment: Parsing *well-written* source code with regex is doable, but the whole approach is error-prone.

Comment: @TamasHegedus if I have it like this `if init then` I want to match `init`

Comment: I don’t think look-behind can solve this problem.  Consider this line:  `/* Needed for requirement 8.1.b */ init();`

Comment: Have fun with multiline comments ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `--` or `/*` are on the same line as the `init`, there are some options.  As the commenters said, multiline comments will likely require stronger techniques.

The simplest way I know is to actually preprocess the strings to remove the `--.*$` and `/\*.*$`, then look for `init` (or `init\b` if you don't want to match `initialization`):

```
String input = "if init then foo";
String checkme = input.replaceAll("--.*$", "").replaceAll("/\\*.*$", "");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("init");  // or "init\\b"
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(checkme);
System.out.println(matcher.find());
```

You can also use negative lookbehind as in @olsli's answer.

Comment: I am expecting the word `init` and `--` or `/*` to be on the same line for now. I want to keep the string preprocessing as a last resort, as I want to try to make an expression for it, but if I have no other option then I will have to process the string before looking for init

Comment: I ended up having to look at each line of my string, and match against the regular expression if it doesn't start with `--` or `/*` and ignoring multiline comments, and for the word init used `\b` before and after `init` as you suggested.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can start with:

```
String input = "/*init";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^((?!--|\\/\\*).)*init");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
System.out.println(matcher.find());
```

Comment: I am trying the expressions in regex101, but it is not matching https://regex101.com/r/bHk1mY/1

Answer (score 0):

I have added more braces to separate things out. This should also work, tested it in Regexr and IDEONE

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?!=((\\/\\*)|(--)))([.]*?)init[.]*$", Pattern.MULTILINE|Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
String s = "/* Initialisation";
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

m.find(); /* should return you >-1 if there's a match
```